# exception Unable to load DLL 'curand64_75'

Tags: aleagpu

Am trying to run the Asian option pricing sample, I have the latest CUDA Drivers installed and get the following error when running.

exception Unable to load DLL 'curand64_75': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Any idea what has gone wrong?

Comment: Yes. It couldn't load *curand64_75.dll*. Do you have that file on your system, in a location that it can be found properly (in the same folder as the app trying to load it or a folder on your PATH)?

Comment: No curand64_75.dll is not on my PC. OS is Windows 10, new Install and have downloaded and installed all the software as specified in http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_2/doc/installation.html

Comment: It appears that you haven't *downloaded and installed all the software* if you have a DLL that's missing.

Comment: I have been checking and it may be a versioning issue. I do have curand64_80.dll found in "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin" windering if the curand64_75.dll is from version 7.5?

Comment: That would be my guess, based on the naming and location.

Comment: I Have installed version 7.5 and now get a different error? exception [cuRAND Error] LAUNCH_FAILURE


0 : GeForce GTX 1070 [6.1] 8192MB
Default GPU: 0
Select device id [0] : 0
Do multi-GPU test? [0|1] : 0
Number of batches : 10
Show progress? [0|1] : 1

Asian option pricing benchmark [GeForce GTX 1070]
Num iterations 1, num batches 10, num samples per batch 10485760
Aprox GPU memory usage: 1040 MB
0 : GeForce GTX 1070 [6.1] 8192MB

Gpu explicit memory management
exception [cuRAND Error] LAUNCH_FAILURE

Comment: try using the newest CUDA driver (8.0) and install the CUDA toolkit 8.0, and configure AleaGPU to use 8.0 toolkit. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41375798/2218586

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** do this instead: [Is AleaGPU compatible with CUDA Toolkit 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354925/is-aleagpu-compatible-with-cuda-toolkit-8-0?rq=1)

It can be solved through app.config: http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_2/doc/faq.html#config_cuda_version just set that to whatever version you have installed.

-- old approach --

Had the same issue, what I did is go to this folder:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\bin\
```

There copied `curand_64_92.dll` and saved it next to it as `curand64_75.dll` (so keeping the original and taking notes so I could roll back).

Then Alea 3.0.4 worked for me. I'm assuming these are all backward compatible, results seem to check out.